# jQuery .width() stops adding to variable with .resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see in the screenshots below, on the last six logs the width doesn't go up it stays the exact same, this only happens when I use jQuery's .resize() function and not with it's on load function which is the screenshot below. I will add the code which adds up the slider width.

Logs with jQuery's .resize() function : 
[image: log jQuery resize function]

Logs with on load function :
[image: log on load]

Here's a pastebin of all the code together https://pastebin.com/9Cf9ZNqt

This is the code that adds up the slider width depending on how many divs inside the slider.

```
sliderWidth = 0;
// Detect the slider width with appended tail
$('>div>div',container).each(function(){
  sliderWidth += $(this).outerWidth(false);
  console.log($(this));
  console.log('slider width: ' + sliderWidth);
});
```

I would like the .resize() function to work the same as the on load function. The width to carry on adding up as normal as it should.

Comment: Log `$(this).outerWidth(false)` or do it in the debugger to see if they are returning what you are expecting

Comment: @Huangism The last four which stay the same do indeed return as 0 with the .resize() you can see here https://i.paste.pics/f5987632393f7ac57f373e179bd64105.png and they don't within the on load function, why are they returning as 0? thank you for helping me

Comment: I have been searching and i believe this issue originates from the images being appended to the slider, i'm not sure whether it is because the images haven't loaded yet

Comment: It's too much code to go thru, on a glance, it looks like on resize you are removing a bunch of stuff then re-initializing the widget again. I don't know why that is being done but that's sure to cause issues and I don't think it should be done that way

Comment: okay sure, I understand, how should it be done then?

Comment: I don't know, all you have is the js, I don't even know why you are removing and reinitializing it. It's best if you could post a simple example of the issue you are having